# Exporting several swf's from single fla

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, jsfl, fla

I have a single fla-file which has several different animations on a main timeline.
Each animation sequence starts with a frame marked with a specific label.

I need to keep the source file this way, but I also need to have separate swf files each with a specific segment from a timeline.
Currently I have to manually change publish settings to a specific swf name, add small changes to the ActionScript in a frame and publish. This procedures has to be done 4 times.

Is there any possibility to run a single jsfl script and make it publish 4 swfs, each one having just a segment of a main timeline?

I've searched the documentation and haven't found any clues. But I've never worked with jsfl though.
Thank you.

Comment: "*I need to keep the source file this way*" why?

Comment: Developers need a single file. But client needs those separated for demonstration.

Comment: how does your timeline look like? in short, i'd iterate through the timeline objects layers and frames and copy each frame corresponding to the an animation to a new document, and export it with jsfl - but there might be other more simple ways

Comment: My timeline has pretty lots of layers. And there are 4 different sequences (they are not splitted in any way), each sequence's first frame is marked by frame label.  Yes, you have a good point. I actually understood that I could make it even easier, all I need is to change an ActionScript via JSFL of my first frame, then change publish settings, and export movie as is, then make it 3 times again. Don't you know whether it's possible to change ActionScript in a frame via JSFL? Thank you.

Comment: absolutely, frames have an `actionScript` property, as seen [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf) in the docs